# cakephp manually building arrays

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a relationship where a quote habtm applicants. I am trying to get a quote to save with multiple applicants at once. I already have an array of the applicants I need but I don't know how to format that array to get it to save when I insert it into the quote array.
The applicant array looks like this:

```
 array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Applicant' => array(
        'id' => '436',
        'clientcase_id' => '66',
        'archive_id' => '1',
        'birthdate' => '2013-09-21 01:41:00',
        'title' => '',
        'first_name' => 'george',
        'middle_name' => 'a',
        'surname' => 'summerlane',
        'email' => 'email@q.com',
        'landline_number' => '88465120.',
        'mobile_number' => '',
        'applicant_type' => '',
        'created' => '2013-09-21 01:43:10',
        'modified' => '2013-09-21 01:43:10'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Applicant' => array(
        'id' => '435',
        'clientcase_id' => '66',
        'archive_id' => '1',
        'birthdate' => '2013-09-21 01:41:00',
        'title' => '',
        'first_name' => 'mary',
        'middle_name' => 's',
        'surname' => 'amnn',
        'email' => 'some@this.cin',
        'landline_number' => '465132',
        'mobile_number' => '',
        'applicant_type' => '',
        'created' => '2013-09-21 01:41:48',
        'modified' => '2013-09-21 01:41:48'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Applicant' => array(
        'id' => '66',
        'clientcase_id' => '66',
        'archive_id' => '1',
        'birthdate' => null,
        'title' => null,
        'first_name' => 'Tania',
        'middle_name' => '',
        'surname' => 'Humphreys',
        'email' => 'purple67@me.com',
        'landline_number' => null,
        'mobile_number' => '0438854355',
        'applicant_type' => 'Main applicant',
        'created' => '2012-10-29 00:00:00',
        'modified' => '2012-10-21 00:00:00'
    )
)
```

)

I need one that looks like this:

```
array(
'Applicants' => array(
    'id' => 435,
    'id' => 436,
    'id' => 66
)
```

)

How might I go about doing this?
Or is there a better way?

When I save a quote the array looks like this:

```
array(
'QuoteButton' => 'Submit',
'Quote' => array(
    'date' => array(
        'day' => '13',
        'month' => '10',
        'year' => '2013'
    ),
    'description' => '',
    'quote_accepted' => '0',
    'research_accepted' => '0',
    'cc_accepted' => '0',
    'pesel_accepted' => '0',
    'setfees_accepted' => '0',
    'total' => '0'
),
'Applicant' => array(
    'id' => '66'
),
```

How do I insert more than one applicant into the array?

Answer (score 0):

An array can't have the same `id`, but can crate another array like this:

```
$datas = array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Applicant' => array(
        'id' => '436',
        'clientcase_id' => '66',
        'archive_id' => '1',
        'birthdate' => '2013-09-21 01:41:00',
        'title' => '',
        'first_name' => 'george',
        'middle_name' => 'a',
        'surname' => 'summerlane',
        'email' => 'email@q.com',
        'landline_number' => '88465120.',
        'mobile_number' => '',
        'applicant_type' => '',
        'created' => '2013-09-21 01:43:10',
        'modified' => '2013-09-21 01:43:10'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Applicant' => array(
        'id' => '435',
        'clientcase_id' => '66',
        'archive_id' => '1',
        'birthdate' => '2013-09-21 01:41:00',
        'title' => '',
        'first_name' => 'mary',
        'middle_name' => 's',
        'surname' => 'amnn',
        'email' => 'some@this.cin',
        'landline_number' => '465132',
        'mobile_number' => '',
        'applicant_type' => '',
        'created' => '2013-09-21 01:41:48',
        'modified' => '2013-09-21 01:41:48'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Applicant' => array(
        'id' => '66',
        'clientcase_id' => '66',
        'archive_id' => '1',
        'birthdate' => null,
        'title' => null,
        'first_name' => 'Tania',
        'middle_name' => '',
        'surname' => 'Humphreys',
        'email' => 'purple67@me.com',
        'landline_number' => null,
        'mobile_number' => '0438854355',
        'applicant_type' => 'Main applicant',
        'created' => '2012-10-29 00:00:00',
        'modified' => '2012-10-21 00:00:00'
    )
)

);

$ids = array();
foreach($datas as $data => $applicants) {
    $ids[] = $applicants['Applicant']['id'];
}

print_r($ids);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 436 [1] => 435 [2] => 66 )
```

How to use the `ids`? Like this:

```
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
   // do whatever you want with the applicant id
}
```

Comment: I can get something like this using a set::classicextract but after I have it I am not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

like tttony pointed out, array indexes need to be unique so i would:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($array as $applicant)
  $ids[$applicant['Applicant']['id']] = null;
```

which will output:

```
Array
(
  [436] => 
  [435] => 
  [66] => 
)
```

now id is key to $ids array...you could add something else as value rather than null